# Apache Ambari agent: sudo exception while running Elasticsearch Datanode services (M-Pack)

Tags: elasticsearch, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to leverage [Elasticsearch 6.3.x (Ambari) M-Pack](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/215078/how-to-install-elk-stack-632-in-ambari.html) for provisioning ES and Kibana services on HDP cluster. The M-Pack got installed smoothly on Ambari Server and ES, Kibana services were installed successfully.

ES Master and Kibana services are up, *but ES Slaves (Data nodes) are not running*. Getting the following exception while trying to start ES Data node service via Ambari:

`resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of 'sudo systemctl daemon-reload' returned 1. sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

How to mitigate aforementioned exception and run ES Datanode services via Ambari?

**Technical Details**

```
HDP version: 2.6.3

Ambari version: 2.6.1.5

Cluster size: 5 nodes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was resolved by trying `non sudo` [variant of M-Pack](https://community.hortonworks.com/storage/attachments/87415-elasticsearch-mpack-2500-9.tar.gz). Ambari Agents were running with root capabilities and do not need additional `sudo`.

Multiple variants are listed under **Downloads** section of the  [Elasticsearch 6.3.x (Ambari) M-Pack page](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/215078/how-to-install-elk-stack-632-in-ambari.html).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a linux issue than HDP issue. Google search got me this: https://www.shell-tips.com/2014/09/08/sudo-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo/